# Как сделать макрос для добавления записей в таблицу?

Tags: access, ms-access

Необходимо макрос, который будет добавлять записи в таблицу "00_tb1_org".

Необходимо чтобы в поле "tb1_id" подставлялось значение записи из счётчика "с" - "по".
Т.е. если в счётчике стоит с =1; по = 3,
то в поле "tb1_id" подставляется значение: 1, 2, 3.

Если в счётчике стоит с =4; по = 6, 
то в поле "tb1_id"подставляется значение: 4, 5, 6.

В остальные поля подставляются однотипные значения.
Т.е. если на форме заполнено:
с =1;
по = 3;
tb1_OrgName = tb1_OrgName знач 1;
tb1_xar1 = tb1_xar1 знач 1;
tb1_xar2 = tb1_xar2 знач 1;

то будет создано три записи.
На скрине рассмотрен результат для двух вариантов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начал пробовать, но что-то выдаёт ошибки

```
Private Sub Кнопка14_Click()
Dim Rst As DAO.Recordset
Set Rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("00_tb1_org")

Rst.AddNew
Rst.tb1_xar1 = tb1_xar1
Rst.tb1_xar2 = tb1_xar2

Rst.Update
Rst.Close
Me.fmSingleQuestionMode.Requery
End Sub
```

Ссылка на файл http://transfiles.ru/gl55e

Comment: `for i = с to по : rst.addnew : ... : rst.update : next i : rst.close`

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ответ. Работает. Кое как сделал, но ме могу понять как сделать, чтобы текст забирался из полей формы, а не из кода, как в приведённом в моём сообщении коде.. Наверное оформляйте как ответ. Dim i As Long
    With Me.Recordset
        For i = Val(Me.start) To Val(Me.finis)
            .AddNew
            !tb1_id = i
            !tb1_OrgName = "Îðã " & i
            !tb1_xar1 = "Îðã " & i & " Õàð 1." & i
            !tb1_xar2 = "Îðã " & i & " Õàð 2." & i
            .Update
        Next
    End With
    Me.Requery